# Parse a list of strings with numbers

Tags: string, list, scheme

I have a list of words. Each word has a numeric value.

```
 '(("Home" 15)("Baby" 20) ("Mother" 28)...)).
```

I have to write a program which gets something like that:

```
(function-name "[Home (Baby3) 2] Mother"))
```

and to calculate their value.

- Each word start with upper-case and all the other words in the word is lower-case.
- Each word get its value from the list above.
- Each word needs to be multiplied by the following number. If there is no number, then 1.

In the example above:

```
"[Home (Baby3) 2] Mother" =  Home*1 + (Baby*3)*2 +Mother*1=15*1+20*3*2+28=163
```

I have no idea how to start this. Any ideas?

I start to write the code.
But, I dont know how to deal with 2 parenthesis [ , for eaxmple
[Home [Baby3] 2].
How can I know if ] clost the first or the second? (without use something like counter and set!)

Comment: You can't really use this place just to get people to do your homework for you.  You should at least consider some possible approaches, explain your thinking and ask for advice on whether the approaches are good.  Better yet, try an approach, see where you hit problems, then ask.

Answer (score 3):

Consider breaking the problem down into stages.  One possible decomposition would be:

1. Figure out how to take arbitrary strings and **parse** them into data structures.  e.g. given `"[Home (Baby3) 2] Mother"`, write a parsing function that turns this into the more digestible, structured value `'((Home (Baby 3) 2) Mother)` or some variation of this.
2. Given such a structured value, write a function to **interpret** it based on the rules you described in your question.

Do you know how to do either of these?

Comment: +1...there's nothing more to say, unless OP shows more effort

Comment: I start to write the code.
But, I dont know how to deal with 2 parenthesis [ , for eaxmple
[Home [Baby3] 2].
How can I know if ] clost the first or the second? (without use something like counter and set!)

Comment: Consider reading about **recursive descent parsing**, which is a fairly straightforward way to parse parenthesized strings.  I have an example of such a parser in the middle of http://hashcollision.org/brainfudge/#(part._.Parsing_the_surface_syntax), but it deals with issues that you probably do not need to deal with.  Stack Overflow should have several references to recursive descent parsing, including: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2405623/looking-for-a-tutorial-on-recursive-descent-parsing